# Rest API authentication issue when called from fetch request in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, rest-api, cookies, authentication

I'm able to use the Rest API for calls that don't need auth, but I'm having an auth issue for the routes that require it. Here is part of a .php view template for an admin page:

```
<div id="nonceCreator">
  <script>
    let _wpnonce = <?php echo json_encode(wp_create_nonce('wp_rest')); ?>;

    let cookiesArray = <?php echo json_encode($_COOKIE) ?>;
  </script>
</div>

<div id="reactScriptInjection">
  <div id="adminRoot"></div>
  <script src="<?php echo PLUGIN_FOLDER_URL . "shared/" ?>adminArea.bundle.js"></script>
</div>
```

The cookies array and nonce seem to pass correctly:

```
wordpress_69cb7e12fdbb27dfb56056fb4f6b39c8: "<username and long key removed>"
wordpress_logged_in_69cb7e12fdbb27dfb56056fb4f6b39c8: "<username and long key removed>"
wordpress_test_cookie: "WP Cookie check"
wp-settings-1: "unfold=1&mfold=o"
wp-settings-time-1: "1562861991
"=====cookiesArray====="

bac3c6<digits removed> =====_wpnonce=====
```

The auth request sends back 401 unauthorized however:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object code: "rest_not_logged_in"
data: {status: 401}
message: "You are not currently logged in."
__proto__: Object
"=====response.json()====="
```

and here is the api call

```
// from the relevant react.js component's source
const getUserNameFromRestApi = () => {
    console.log(_wpnonce, `=====_wpnonce=====`);

    fetch('http://localhost/wptest2/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/me', {
      method : 'get',
      mode : 'cors',
      headers : {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'X-WP-Header' : _wpnonce
      }
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response.json(), `=====response.json()=====`))
      .catch(error => console.log(error, `=====error=====`));
  };
```

I don't think Access Control Origin plays a factor yet as I'm loading the output bundle.js within an admin page in wordpress.

However, I was able to get another plugin to do a successful authenticated fetch. Only difference was that plugin didn't use react.js, but rather vanilla javascript instead.

I thought cookies might be the problem but you see the $_COOKIE array output above. Also the nonce worked in that other plugin so I think I set it up correctly above too.

What else could it be then? I'm thinking something is wrong with the data flow.

Comment: I would strongly advise against putting cookies in a JS array for security reasons, JS can already access cookies directly

Comment: Good to know, I will look into it. FYI this was just for debugging and the plugin is not public facing yet

Comment: Is that `X-WP-Header` just a typo in the question? Because it should be `X-WP-Nonce` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ that was indeed the issue, good catch and thanks

Comment: @SallyCJ can you post that as a proper answer so I can upvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the correct name for the REST API nonce *header* — the correct name is `X-WP-Nonce`, but you used `X-WP-Header`:

```js
fetch('http://localhost/wptest2/?rest_route=/wp/v2/users/me', {
  method : 'get',
  mode : 'cors',
  headers : {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
    'X-WP-Header' : _wpnonce // here you used the wrong name
  }
})
```

Reference from the [REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/):

> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be
>   passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to
>   `wp_rest`. These can then be passed to the API via the `_wpnonce` data
>   parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via
>   the **`X-WP-Nonce` header**.

So make sure to use the correct header name. :)